# How to create Year, Month and date as a combobox in android

Tags: android, xml

how to create Year, Month and Day as a combo box, I can't see combobox in android.
I want to choose Year Only, Month Only and Date Only in a single line in xml and UI design. How should I Do.

Comment: do you need something like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: I can't adjust as i wish and Should I put 3 spinner in a line for year,month and date.

Comment: Give an example , how can you set the three in a single line?